# right click menu - select search

Tags: contextual-menu, search-engine

Is there any way to customise the right click mouse menu that pops up over a highlighted word or phrase?

I normally use Firefox, occasionally Safari or Brave.  Normally DuckDuckGo to search, occasionally Google.

But if I highlight something, for example in an iMessage, and right click I'll always get "Search Google for ...." if search is set to Google in Safari.  Or "Search DuckDuckGo for .... " if that's how Safari is set.

So at the very least I'd like two options available - for two different search engines as in "Search Google for ...."/"Search DuckDuckGo for .... ".

Valhalla would be the ability to select the browser too.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in Safari. It uses whichever search engine you define in Safari preferences. And the same applies to Google. Best I can do is use the one option they offer. I  don't know about other browsers.  There might be a programmatic way to do it but I don't know how to do it.

In Safari, it's way easier to change search engine. Go to address bar  (<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>), enter space(<kbd>spacebar</kbd>), choose search engine. There's no need to go to Safari preferences to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Set your browser to Duck Duck Go. You can always get google results by adding bang g **!g** on any search if you don’t find what you want first from the Duck.

- https://duckduckgo.com/bang